# How to get source code of multiple lambdas inside a single line in Python

Tags: python

Now I have a chained function calls which is similar to the Pandas.

```
df.id.map(lambda x: x + 1).map(lambda y: y + 2)
```

In `map` function, I try to get the source code of the lambda.

I use the `inspect.getsource`, but it just gets the entire line, 
how can I get the exact source code of the right lambda function?

Comment: If the logic of the `map` function depends on the order of it being called, maybe you can send an optional counter argument. Something like - `df.id.map(lambda x: x + 1, 1).map(lambda y: y + 2, 2)` (Better way would be to add a counter and keep incrementing it using `counter++`)

Comment: @Kamehameha It seems that the API looks terrible for the users

Answer (score 2):

The source code position of a lambda isn't actually tracked with more than line granularity. (This has led to [at least one Python interpreter bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue25843).) Unless you want to parse the source code for lambda expressions and figure out which one(s) could have compiled to the lambda object you're inspecting, you can't do better than grabbing the whole line.

Comment: Yeah, I can parse the whole line, and get all lambda functions, but I can't figure out which one is the actual lambda object I am inspecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to switch from standard lambda syntax to [mini_lambda](https://smarie.github.io/python-mini-lambda/) then you get this feature built-in since each lambda expression becomes printable. The same goes for other lambda expression providers such as SymPy